# Shortcode Causing Product Search To Break

Tags: php, wordpress, search, mobile, shortcode

We have added a live product search shortcode on the top of our website for mobile devices only.

On desktops we have left the live product search in a side bar.

We have a function that only calls and places the shortcode for mobile devices.

Previously when you done a live product search on desktop devices and hit enter, 20 products would be returned and made visible in a grid view on the screen.

Since adding the shortcode for mobile devices, this has broken this feature for desktop devices.
The products still appear in a drop down menu, but previously you could hit enter and they would be moved into a nice grid view display in the centre of the screen.

To achieve this before, to enable the products to appear in the centre of the screen, the following line of code was added:

```
if (get_option( 'wpsc_default_category' ) == 'list' && isset($wp_query- 
>query_vars['search_terms']))
$output = false;
}
```

Section of code with the above code having been added at the bottom:

```
function wpsc_display_categories() {
global $wp_query;
$output = false;
if ( !is_numeric( get_option( 'wpsc_default_category' ) ) && ! get_query_var( 'product_tag' ) ) {

    if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['products'] ) )
        $category_id = $wp_query->query_vars['products'];
    else if ( isset( $_GET['products'] ) )
        $category_id = $_GET['products'];

    // if we have no categories, and no search, show the group list
    if ( is_numeric( get_option( 'wpsc_default_category' ) ) || (isset( $product_id ) && is_numeric( $product_id )) )
        $output = true;
    if ( (get_option( 'wpsc_default_category' ) == 'all+list'))
        $output = true;

    if (get_option( 'wpsc_default_category' ) == 'list' && (!isset($wp_query->query_vars['wpsc_product_category']) || !isset($wp_query->query_vars['product_tag']) && get_option('wpsc_display_categories')))
        $output = true;

    if (get_option( 'wpsc_default_category' ) == 'list' && isset($wp_query->query_vars['search_terms']))
        $output = false;
}

if ( isset( $category_id ) && $category_id > 0 )
    $output = false;
if ( get_option( 'wpsc_display_categories' ))
    $output = true;

return $output;
}
```

Not sure why adding the shortcode has broken the products returning in the centre of the screen, from the first line of code shown at the top here?

It's strange as the function we have that adds the shortcode for mobiles, checks that it's a mobile device and only applies the shortcode for mobile devices.

Any thoughts, or ideas on how we can solve this one?

Current filter in functions.php which checks for the mobile devices, and applies the shortcode if a mobile device is detected:

```
add_action( 'generate_inside_navigation','tu_add_to_mobile_bar' );
function tu_add_to_mobile_bar() { 

if (wp_is_mobile()) {
?>
<div class="search">
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[our shortcode in here] ' ); ?>
</div>
<?php
}}
```

Comment: How are you programmatically determining when a request comes in that it is for a "mobile device"? Are using UA detection? Or do you just have two search boxes, one for "desktop" and one for "responsive", that you are showing/hiding, and you are passing something to the server that says which is being shown? (Hopefully it is this one.)

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for your input. Yes. Have 2 live search boxes. One for desktop and one for mobile. The desktop one is hidden with some CSS, for mobile devices, and the mobile one is only called for mobile devices, within our functions.php file, with the following check in our filter there: if (wp_is_mobile()) {

Comment: I would not trust `wp_is_mobile` at all. It is user-agent based and the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/) literally says "Do not think of this function as a way of detecting phones". I would recommend including an additional "something" in the request, an additional field or query string, that identifies it as your mobile search, and then perform your server-side logic basic on that.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Can you think of an additional check that we could add in the request?

Comment: If it is a GET request, just add a `is_mobile=true` to the query string, if it is a POST request do the same but with a field. For the former, you might need to register it with [`query_vars`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/) first. WP won't know what to do with it, but you can then access it using `get_query_var('is_mobile')`

Comment: Thanks Chris. Much appreciated! If I paste the complete function that we have that checks for mobile devices, would you mind having a quick look to see how your suggestions could be incorporated to make the changes? Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: We always encourage everyone to most all relevant code, so yes. I'll try my best to take a look at it when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I've added the code snippet that we have in our functions.php file, which checks for a mobile device, and then applies the shortcode, if a mobile device is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the gist of what I was talking about.

**Step #1 - Register a variable with the global query**

This isn't technically 100% necessary, but it is generally considered a best practice. You could alternatively just inspect the raw `$_GET` or `$_POST` globals.

```php
add_filter(
    'query_vars',
    function( $vars ) {
        $vars[] = 'is_mobile_search';
        return $vars;
    }
);
```

**Step #2 - Pass the variable**

I'm assuming your shortcode actually renders a form, and that you can conditionally change it somehow, maybe `[our_shortcode mobile="true"]`.

```html
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="is_mobile_search" value="true" />
</form>
```

**Step #3 - Use the variable**

The contents of this function are your normal stuff, you are just checking `is_mobile_search` for the literal (but arbitrary) string value of `true`.

```php
function wpsc_display_categories() {
    $is_mobile_search = get_query_var('is_mobile_search') === "true";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Much appreciated! Will give your suggestion a go, and let you know how we get on! Thanks again for your time and help on this!